# Download a PDF file from Laravel Voyager storage

Tags: php, laravel-6, voyager

I have a problem downloading a pdf file in laravel with voyager. Someone said, i have to use 'json_decode' but I cant understand how to do so. Here is my controller:

**Controller**

```php
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $posts = Post::all();
        $files = Download::all();

        return view('user.index', compact('posts', 'files'));
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        $files = Download::where('id', $id)->firstOrFail();
        $path = storage_path($files->file);

        return response()->download($path);
    }
}
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('/download/{id}','HomeController@show')->name(downloadFile);
```

**View**

```php
@foreach($files as $file)
    <a class="primary-btn" href="{{route('downloadFile',$file->id)}}">Download Resume </a>
@endforeach
```

> The file 
>   "C:\laragon\www\kbtonmoy.com\storage[{"download_link":"downloads\January2020\tmUxP8s9Tvzzqwnl7nxT.pdf","original_name":"ridita.pdf"}]"
>   does not exist

Answer (score 0):

At first check your **$path** 
I think you shouldn't use storage_path() function.
Because Voyager store file info in json format.
I guess you should try this.

**Controller**

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $posts = Post::all();
        $files = Download::all();

        return view('user.index', compact('posts', 'files'));
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        $files = Download::where('id', $id)->firstOrFail();

        //$path = storage_path($files->file);

        $new_file = json_decode($files->file)[0];
        $new_file_path = Voyager::image($new_file->download_link);

        $new_file_name = $new_file->original_name; //if you need original file name
        $new_file_size = round((Storage::disk(config('voyager.storage.disk'))->size($new_file->download_link)) / (1024*1024) ,4) ; //if you need file size in MB

        return response($new_file_path);
    }
}
```

**View**

```
@foreach($files as $file)
    <a class="primary-btn" href="{{route('downloadFile',$file->id)}}" download>Download Resume </a>
@endforeach
```

But I think you should normalize the code by using relationship in **Download** Model

So then you do not need to route on show function

Then it may look like this

**Controller**

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $posts = Post::all();
        $files = Download::all();

        return view('user.index', compact('posts', 'files'));
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<?php 
foreach($files as $file){
    $new_file = json_decode($file->file)[0];
    $new_file_path = Voyager::image($new_file->download_link);

    $new_file_name = $new_file->original_name; //if you need original file name
    $new_file_size = round((Storage::disk(config('voyager.storage.disk'))->size($new_file->download_link)) / (1024*1024) ,4) ; //if you need file size in MB
?>
    <a class="primary-btn" href="{{$new_file_path}}" download>Download Resume </a>
<?php
}
?>
```

Hope it help you.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but your solution returns "The file HTTP:\\............pdf does not exist"